# How to decode NOAA TREND files?

Tags: dataset

How do I decode NOAA TREND files such as:

ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/trend/KABQ.TREND

I know how to decode METAR, SYNOP, SHIP, and BUOY files, but not these.

[is there a better place to post this?]

Comment: Stack Overflow question.

Comment: What do you mean by decode? I.e. convert to what format/import to what program?

Comment: Decode meaning understand. What do these files say? It looks like gibberish to me.

Comment: Ok, this justifies it can stay here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of this is possible to decode.

For example, compare part of that file (as of now)

```
0:Aug 28:08|672:91.0 (32.8):46.9 (8.3):30.04 (1017):W 7:...
```

then `91.0 (32.8)` is temperature in F(C), while `46.9 (8.3)` is dew point in F(C), `30.04 (1017)` is pressure in inches Hg (hPa), `W 7` is wind direction (source) and speed in mph.  I would guess `08|672` might means hours into August, and `0` might mean most recent, but this is not so obvious.

Compare with ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/decoded/KABQ.TXT

Comment: Thanks, Henry. So you think this is a string of multiple decoded METAR observations all run together? Seems like an odd thing to distribute publicly.

Comment: @barrycarter: My guess is that it is the data for the last 24 hours.

Comment: OK. I thought I'd found something really new and exciting :)

Comment: 0:Aug ... 0 means 0h UTC, i think. The file is 24h and updated cyclic UTC
0:
1:
...:
23: